# Zookeeper not recovering after timeout

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper is not properly recovering after timeout and falling into a non working state without restarting.

What can cause this, how can we resolve it?

config

```
      ZOO_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOO_INIT_LIMIT: 30000
      ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT: 10
      ZOO_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 2000
      ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED: 'false'
      ZOO_AUTOPURGE_PURGEINTERVAL: 1
      ZOO_AUTOPURGE_SNAPRETAINCOUNT: 10
      ZOO_LOG4J_PROP: INFO,ROLLINGFILE
```

log

```
2020-01-10 20:58:57,473 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x2200061493 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x22 (n.peerEPoch), FOLLOWING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 20:59:57,484 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x2200061493 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x22 (n.peerEPoch), FOLLOWING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:00:57,495 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 2 (n.leader), 0x2200061493 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x22 (n.peerEPoch), FOLLOWING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,510 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Follower@96] - Exception when following the leader
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:85)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:99)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Learner.readPacket(Learner.java:158)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.followLeader(Follower.java:92)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1271)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,516 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Follower@201] - shutdown called
java.lang.Exception: shutdown Follower
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Follower.shutdown(Follower.java:201)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:1275)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,516 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):LearnerZooKeeperServer@165] - Shutting down
2020-01-10 21:01:07,517 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):ZooKeeperServer@558] - shutting down
2020-01-10 21:01:07,517 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FollowerRequestProcessor@139] - Shutting down
2020-01-10 21:01:07,518 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):CommitProcessor@362] - Shutting down
2020-01-10 21:01:07,518 [myid:1] - INFO  [FollowerRequestProcessor:1:FollowerRequestProcessor@110] - FollowerRequestProcessor exited loop!
2020-01-10 21:01:07,518 [myid:1] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:1:CommitProcessor@195] - CommitProcessor exited loop!
2020-01-10 21:01:07,518 [myid:1] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:1:CommitProcessor@195] - CommitProcessor exited loop!
2020-01-10 21:01:07,526 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FinalRequestProcessor@514] - shutdown of request processor complete
2020-01-10 21:01:07,659 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):SyncRequestProcessor@191] - Shutting down
2020-01-10 21:01:07,660 [myid:1] - INFO  [SyncThread:1:SyncRequestProcessor@169] - SyncRequestProcessor exited!
2020-01-10 21:01:07,661 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):QuorumPeer@1318] - PeerState set to LOOKING
2020-01-10 21:01:07,661 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):QuorumPeer@1193] - LOOKING
2020-01-10 21:01:07,664 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FastLeaderElection@885] - New election. My id =  1, proposed zxid=0x23007a7d69
2020-01-10 21:01:07,666 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x23007a7d69 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x23 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,668 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x2200061493 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LEADING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x23 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,668 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x23007a7d69 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 2 (n.sid), 0x23 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:01:07,870 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):QuorumPeer@1281] - LEADING
2020-01-10 21:01:07,885 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Leader@66] - TCP NoDelay set to: true
2020-01-10 21:01:07,885 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Leader@86] - zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshots = 10
2020-01-10 21:01:07,885 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Leader@88] - zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshotTimeout = 5
2020-01-10 21:01:07,890 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):ZooKeeperServer@938] - minSessionTimeout set to 4000
2020-01-10 21:01:07,890 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):ZooKeeperServer@947] - maxSessionTimeout set to 40000
2020-01-10 21:01:07,890 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):ZooKeeperServer@166] - Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /datalog/version-2 snapdir /data/version-2
2020-01-10 21:01:07,900 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Leader@464] - LEADING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 29 MS
2020-01-10 21:01:07,918 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FileTxnSnapLog@384] - Snapshotting: 0x23007a7d69 to /data/version-2/snapshot.23007a7d69
2020-01-10 21:01:07,964 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,040 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,318 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,491 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,491 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-4:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,501 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,501 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,509 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,510 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-4:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,519 [myid:1] - INFO  [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@679] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 3 (n.leader), 0x23007a7d72 (n.zxid), 0x2 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 3 (n.sid), 0x23 (n.peerEPoch), LEADING (my state)0 (n.config version)
2020-01-10 21:01:08,524 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,524 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,535 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,535 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-4:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,545 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,545 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,572 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,574 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-4:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,582 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,583 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-3:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,594 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,594 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
2020-01-10 21:01:08,595 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: ZooKeeperServer not running
...
```

Comment: the initLimit seems too large. As is, it actually corresponds to 60000seconds, almost 17hours !?

Comment: how big are snapshots in /data/version-2/ ?

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin around 1 GB, stored on NVME SSDs

Answer (score 2):

For the typical symptomatic categories listed above, use the lists below to check if you are seeing frequent disconnects of healthy clients

1. Network connectivity problems​:

   - Use ifconfig to check a number of errors on NIC's. If high, this can
     account for increased latency.
2. I/O starvation​

   - It's better if Zookeeper is installed on dedicated nodes when high performance is needed
   - Check your HDD performance, e.g. using hdparm -tT
   - Make sure that directory for ZK transaction log (/opt/mapr/zkdata by default) is on fast dedicated drive
   - Property is dataLogDir in the $ZK_DIR/conf/zoo.cfg
   - Make sure that ZooKeeper heap size is not larger than the RAM available to avoid swapping
3. GC starvation
   ​​- The symptom is frequent client disconnects and session expiration due to starvation of heartbeat thread.

   - Use jstat -gc to see if there are frequent full garbage collections
   - Use alternative GC collector, if issue is present, like for example ConcurrentMarkSweep. For this, put   -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
4. Client-side timeouts

   - Check swapping on client machines free -m.
5. Possibly increase maxSessionTimeout if set to too low value
6. If no obvious problems detected, run https://github.com/phunt/zk-smoketest to check if the problem is with zookeeper at all
7. Virtual Environments - if ZK cluster is on some shared hosting, this can cause resource starvation and introduce latency.

Reference link : https://mapr.com/support/s/article/How-do-I-troubleshoot-ZK-connection-timeout-issues?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

This

> `2020-01-10 21:01:07,900 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):Leader@464] - LEADING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 29 MS`
>
> `2020-01-10 21:01:07,918 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FileTxnSnapLog@384] - Snapshotting: 0x23007a7d69 to /data/version-2/snapshot.23007a7d69`

is telling me, the zk node became leader and it started writing snapshot (after that, it is probably going to send snapshot to followers). Then node will start serving queries. But if snapshot is big (or /data/version-2/ underlying hardware is slow) writing will take significant amount of time. If it takes longer than `maxSessionTimeout 40000`, all active sessions and all *ephemeral* data will be lost.

If that is the case, then the only good way to avoid it is to reduce amount of data stored in zookeeper. For example, store heavy blobs somewhere else (file/nfs/hdfs/aws/sql/http/...), and in zk only write timestamps (and path in storage maybe), so that the application still could receive data-change-notications quickly from zk.

Comment: All of the files together are around 1GB and stored on NVME SSDs